# Three.js: Changing camera position prevents movement

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a problem where upon changing the position of the initial camera location, I can no longer move it. Here is my code below:

The initial set position:

```
camera.position.set (0, 1.67, 10);
```

Now under this condition I will change the Z position of the camera:

```
if (cube.material.opacity == 0.2) {
    camera.position.set (0, 1.67, 0);
}
```

I am using this script to move the camera with keyboard events:

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', onKeyDown, false );

distance = 0.05;

function onKeyDown() {
    switch( event.keyCode ) {
        case 87:
            camera.translateZ( - distance );
            break;
        case 83:
            camera.translateZ( distance );
            break;
        case 65:
            camera.translateX( - distance );
            break;
        case 68:
            camera.translateX(  distance );

    }
};
```

After changing the Z position from `10` to `0`, the camera stutters back and forth when pressing the keys and no longer moves. How can I fix this? Thank you.

Comment: What about that, if you change `camera.translateZ( - distance );` to `camera.position.z -= distance;` (and so on for the other keys) ?

Comment: That made no difference. I think the problem is after the condition, the camera is "set" in place in the z axis and cannot be moved however, moving along the x axis is fine. I have no idea how to fix it though.

Comment: you probably have the repositioning of the camera (your second code snippet) inside the render/update loop. This makes the position to be set every time you render. Can you post a little more context to this code?

Comment: I figured it was something like that. I changed the camera's position as well as the rendered scene hence why. Would I have to create a new camera?

Comment: If you change the camera position during the loop, it will keep changing the position as long as the condition is met. Also, more code can help us understand your problem. Would you post your animate function?